# Findstr from text with more strings

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I  have a file that has text formatted like this:

```
Station Number : 1 , IP: 10.1.1.10 
01:28:39.540  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful

Station Number : 3 , IP: 10.1.3.10
01:35:32.217  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful

Station Number : 4 , IP: 10.1.4.10 
01:25:33.382  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful

Station Number : 6 , IP: 10.1.6.10 
01:23:16.958  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
```

---

i want to make a file that will collect data from it to be like this:

`Station Number : X,Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful`

I've tried with findstr and got stucked, thanx for the help!

26.1.2014 EDIT::::
hey guys! thanks for the help & quick reply!
I've made this one:

```
:: day sets ::
set mm=%date:~-10,2%
set dd=%date:~-7,2%
set yyyy=%date:~-4%
set TODAY=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
set filenotfound=********************* %%A , File Not Found *********************
set Computerslist=IPST.TXT
set LOG=C:\MaintSRV\%today%_MaintSRV_All_Stations.TXT

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%Computerslist%) do (
    cls
    @echo Collecting MaintSrv Status From Station Number : %%A
    for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('findstr /c:"was finished with status" \\%%B.10\C\office\services\log\MAINTSRV-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.LOG') DO @echo St %%A   %%F>>%log%
    IF EXIST "\\%%B.10\C\office\services\log\MAINTSRV-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.LOG" (echo complete) ELSE (echo %filenotfound%>>%log%) 
    )
```

it works great but I got some points (........) that I want to be erased.
this is the output:

```
St 1   01:28:55.329  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 3   01:36:32.913  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 4   01:26:00.125  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 6   01:23:33.416  ..........  ..........  ....................  ....................  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
```

and this is the wanted output:

```
St 1   01:28:55.329  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 3   01:36:32.913  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 4   01:26:00.125  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 6   01:23:33.416  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
```

Comment: Can you show us the (non-functional) code you have already?

Comment: I would use a `for /F` command and first store the `Station number`, and in the next record I would show one result...

Comment: Did you want the result `Successful` on the second line, as you've shown?

Comment: Your example code use a file not described in the original question! Anyway, I think your code generate all status lines for each station; that is: `St 1 01:28:...` `St 1 01:36:...` `St 1 01:26:...` `St 1 01:23:...` `St 3 01:28:...` `St 3 01:36:...` `St 3 01:26:...` `St 3 01:23:...` `St 4 01:28:...` `St 4 01:36:...` `St 4 01:26:...` `St 4 01:23:...` `St 6 01:28:...` `St 6 01:36:...` `St 6 01:26:...` `St 6 01:23:...`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344435/findstr-from-text-with-more-strings/21376096#21376096) below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Batch file generate the output as you said below "this is the wanted output":

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "St="
(for /F "tokens=1-5*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined St (
      set St=%%D
   ) else (
      echo St !St!   %%A  %%F
      set "St="
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Giving your input file in `input.txt`, this is the generated `output.txt`:

```
St 1   01:28:39.540  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 3   01:35:32.217  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 4   01:25:33.382  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
St 6   01:23:16.958  Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I mean by nesting the for loops:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%i in (some.log) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:," %%j in ("%%i") do (
    if "%%j"=="Station Number " (
      set _num=%%k
      set _num=!_num: =!
    ) else (
      set _task=%%i
      set _task=!_task:~82!
      echo Station Number : !_num!,!_task!>>new.log
    )
  )
)

endlocal
```

Given your input file is `some.log`, here is what the `new.log` file looks like after running the batch file.

```
Station Number : 1,Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
Station Number : 3,Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
Station Number : 4,Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
Station Number : 6,Task: Office & Ej Hot Backup was finished with status: Successful
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to suit the new format requested in the changed question

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" |repl ".*r : (\d+).*\r\n(.*?) .*(Task.*)" "St $1   $2   $3" xm >"newfile.txt"
```

Comment: I don't know why you didn't answer my question - here's an updated answer for you.